# Butterworth filter damping

Tags: filter, damping-factor, butterworth

A Butterworth filter has a damping ratio of 0.707 and is critically damped, but in general a damping ratio of 1 is critically damped, what is the theory behind this?

Comment: A Butterworth filter is underdamped, because the damping ratio is less than 1. Actually, for a Butterworth filter only \$ Q = \zeta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$.

Comment: There is a direct relation between the pole-quality factor (Qp) and the damping ratio d: Qp=1/2d . Hence, for a Butterworth response with d=0.7071 we have Qp=0.7071. For critical damping with Qp=0.5 we have d=1.

Answer (score 1):

> *A Butterworth filter has a damping ratio of 0.707 and is critically damped*

No, that is incorrect; a Butterworth filter does has a damping ratio (\$\zeta\$) of \$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$ but, because of this, it cannot be critically damped (\$\zeta=1\$). A damping ratio of 1 means critical damping. Maybe you are confusing lack of ripple in the frequency domain with lack of overshoot in the time domain? Here's a plot of the spectral response and the step-change transient response from [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html): -

[image]

As you should be able to see, a step-change input results in an overshoot of about 4.322% for a 2nd order Butterworth low-pass filter made from and RLC combination.

Comment: But why we take the butterworth filter Q-factor as 0.707

Comment: @Vish that produces a maximally flat passband in the spectrum. A damping ratio less than 0.7071 will produce peaking in the spectrum and so, the Butterworth is regarded as a cornerstone filter. There is also a Bessel filter that has a damping ratio greater than 0.7071 (0.866 from memory) that produces another cornerstone response where the time delay of the filter is constant up to a certain frequency in the spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Vish If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

A 2nd order Butterworth has a characteristic polynomial of \$s^2+\sqrt{2}\,s+1\$ (simplified with \$\omega_{_0}=1\$.) This means that \$2\zeta=\sqrt{2}\$ or that \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{2}\$. This isn't critically damped. That would be \$\zeta=1\$.

I don't think critically damped 2nd order low-pass filters are used in isolation. Usually, by the time you get to Bessel, \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{3}\$, with very tight grouping of frequency delays passing through it, there's not much to be gained by a further lowering of \$Q\$.

You will find nearly critically damped 2nd order filters in longer filter chains. For example, in a 6th order low pass Bessel the first section will have a damping factor that gets close, \$\zeta\approx0.98\$ . And similarly so for a 6th order low pass Butterworth whose first section has \$\zeta=\frac14\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)\approx 0.966\$. But things start getting pretty difficult, using discrete parts and tweaking well, as the order goes much past this point.

You likely won't see critically damped 2nd order filter stages, though a combination of two 1st order active filters chained together must always yield \$\zeta=1\$. (A 2nd order band pass with a large fractional bandwidth, perhaps?)

A Butterworth 2nd order low pass achieves the half-power point right when \$\omega=\omega_{_0}\$. A 2nd order low-pass filter, critically damped, would be at the quarter-power point when \$\omega=\omega_{_0}\$. Or, put another way, a critically damped 2nd order low-pass filter would be at half-power when \$\frac{\omega}{\omega_{_0}}\approx 0.6436\$. (I used an equation solver to get that number, not simulation.) Here's an LTspice run of a 2nd order low pass with \$\zeta=1\$ and \$f_{_0}=10\:\text{kHz}\$:

[image]

Note that the \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ point is where I said it would be in this case.

At [this link](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/second-order-filters.html) you will find the following statement:

[image]

It's possible you picked up your idea from that web site.

You can skim over the [wikipedia article on damping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping). It may help a little.

Comment: Why we take butterworth Q-factor as 0.707

Comment: @Vish That's a different question. But National Instruments has a [short description here](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvanlsconcepts/lvac_butterworth_filters.html) that may help a little. There's mathematics behind your question and it would take a little time to write it down and explain it. That's why I say it is a different question to ask.

Comment: @Vish But I guess that you need to first understand that ***all*** 2nd order low pass filter shapes are entirely covered by this single transfer function: \$\frac1{s^2+2\zeta\,s+1}\$. There's only one variable. And it controls the shape, which is \$\zeta\$. (Or \$Q=\frac1{2\,\zeta}\$, which is just another way of saying the same thing.) The Butterworth has only one shape: the shape defined by \$\zeta=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\$.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.